# Missing OpenJDK Java8 in "Open with" in Ubuntu 15.04 when trying to run .jar file

Tags: java

I'm a complete novice to ubuntu, so i do hope that someone can guide me through so i can chose OpenJDK Java8 in "Open with" menu in Ubuntu 15.04 when trying to run .jar file

Answer (score 2):

There is no `desktop` file in the `openjdk-8` packages.
Therefore you have to create your own `desktop` file:

- Create a new `desktop` file

  ```
  nano ~/.local/share/applications/openjdk8.desktop
  ```
- Add the definitions below

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Encoding=UTF-8
  Name=Open JDK 8 Runtime
  Comment=Open JDK 8 Runtime
  Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -jar %f
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
  Icon=java
  MimeType=application/x-java-archive;application/java-archive;application/x-jar;
  NoDisplay=true
  ```
- Restart `nautilus`

  ```
  nautilus -q
  ```